# Ubuntu 18.04 Freeze after login but wayland works fine

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I saw people asked the similar question but I tried all the solutions, so far non of them can fix my issue. I think the cause might be different so I posted a new one.

My computer is hp elitebook 850 G6. Intel® Core™ i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8 with Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2).

If I login to the normal ubuntu then the system will freeze, no response from mouse, keyboard. Numlock doesn't light up, so does the caps lock. I tried to reinstall graphic driver it didn't help.

It is known after I installed the virtualbox, and some package for the virtual machine but I accidentally installed it into the host machine. After I rebooted the host machine, I cannot login to ubuntu unless to use wayland.

Has anyone faced the same issue? Is there solution for this situation?

Edit:
The output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox*`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                 Version         Architecture    Description
+++-====================-===============-===============-=============================================
ii  virtualbox           5.2.34-dfsg-0~u amd64           x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
un  virtualbox-2.0       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.1       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.2       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.0       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.1       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.2       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.0       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.1       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.2       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.3       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.0       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.1       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.2       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
rc  virtualbox-6.1       6.1.4-136177~Ub amd64           Oracle VM VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-dkms      5.2.34-dfsg-0~u all             x86 virtualization solution - kernel module s
ii  virtualbox-ext-pack  5.2.34-1~ubuntu all             extra capabilities for VirtualBox, downloader
un  virtualbox-guest-add <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-dkm <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-mod <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-sou <none>          <none>          (no description available)
rc  virtualbox-guest-uti 5.2.34-dfsg-0~u amd64           x86 virtualization solution - non-X11 guest u
rc  virtualbox-guest-x11 5.2.34-dfsg-0~u amd64           x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utili
un  virtualbox-modules   <none>          <none>          (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose       <none>          <none>          (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-qt        5.2.34-dfsg-0~u amd64           x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user i
un  virtualbox-source    <none>          <none>          (no desjason@my-organization:~/gujason@ljasjasojasojasojj
```

`dpkg -l *virtualbox* shows:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

`dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii` shows nothing now

Comment: What package did you install on the host computer? Do you have any other accounts on this computer? If so, can you log in there?

Comment: I only have one account, I will try to add accounts and try. But at the end of the day, I just want to use my original account to login to the system. I installed `virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe`, there might be some more packages I don't remmeber but it's all about making the clipboard works in the VM which should be installed in VM. I also did `sudo VBoxClient --clipboard`. But after I realized I shouldn't install them into the host, I removed those packages but didn't help.

Comment: Tested with another admin account, still freeze after login to normal ubuntu but fine with wayland. Tried usb keyboard, built-in keyboard, no response from numlock/capslock. It is completely frozen not just the display. `ctrl+alt+F2` login fine though.

Comment: The reason to try another account was to determine if the problem is with your original accout, or systemic. Do two things. Try disabling Secure Boot in your BIOS and then retry either account. Also, edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *virtualbox*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for explaining, I appreciate your help. I've disabled the `Secure Boot` option while I was trying to make the bidirectional clipboard to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you mixed/matched various VirtualBox softwares on the host. Normally I wouldn't think it would effect how you're booting... but here we are.

In Wayland... since that works for you right now... do...

`sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms`

`sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-ext-pack`

`sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-qt`

`reboot`

To reinstall VirtualBox on the host, you just need to do...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1`

**Update #1:**

- try booting an older kernel from the GRUB menu

  - retest
- try booting using `nomodeset`

  - at the GRUB menu, hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to enter edit mode
  - find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset"
  - hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting
  - retest

**Update #2:**

- Time to reinstall Ubuntu. Uncheck the "format" checkbox and it'll leave your /home alone.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same issue, now the dpkg shows only two lines of `un  virtualbox-gue <none>       <none>       (no description available)`. I suspect the virtualbox might did something changes on my system. I tried advance boot option and login as previous ubuntu version, didn't help.

Comment: @JasonLiu Edit your question with this new command... `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`.

Comment: I updated the question, thank you.

Comment: @JasonLiu Please see Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: Different kernel still have the same behavior. I added the nomodeset and got stuck at `/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 554601/13950976 files, 12622210/55778560 blocks`, ctrl+alt+f2 or f3 doesn't work, has to reboot and change back.

Comment: One last try... in `terminal` type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`, select gdm3, you may get a reload error message, that's ok, then reboot, retest.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` return nothing, no error, no message. I rebooted it and still freeze with normal ubuntu. I guess at this point, it might be worthy to reinstall the OS.

Comment: Time to reinstall Ubuntu. Uncheck the "format" checkbox and it'll leave your /home alone. Report back.

Comment: I get it fixed now, thank you for all the advises and help.

Comment: @JasonLiu  You're very welcome! Good job!